# How to update angular localstorage service after period of 7 days?

Tags: angularjs

I am setting data into my `LocalStoargeService` from an Api request response

```
WishListService.getWishListTags(function(response) {
                var WISHLIST_TAGS_STORAGE_KEY = 'wishlist_tags';
                localStorageService.set(WISHLIST_TAGS_STORAGE_KEY, response.data);
            });
```

Now I want to update this data in the LocalStorageService after period of 7 days from the same Api request.

Comment: When you call an api set a new call time. And check that time in your service. If time is behind, call that service again and set new time.

Comment: could u give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call an api set a new call time. And check that time in your service. If time is behind, call that service again and set new time.

You can use $promise for that kind of calls. Here is a simple example for you. You can call `callWishList` whenever you want whish_list.

```
function updateWishList(response){
    var WISHLIST_TAGS_STORAGE_KEY = 'wishlist_tags';
    localStorageService.set(WISHLIST_TAGS_STORAGE_KEY, response.data);
}

function getWishList(){
    var WISHLIST_TAGS_STORAGE_KEY = 'wishlist_tags';
    return localStorageService.get(WISHLIST_TAGS_STORAGE_KEY);
}

function callWishList(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    //check last update time
    //last_update is a date
    var last_update = localStorageService.get("wish_list_update_date");
    var now_date = new Date();
    if(now_date.getTime()>last_update.getTime()){
        //this means you need to update your data and last_update
        $http.post("myWishListFromServerURL", {})
                .success(function (response) {
                    localStorageService.set("wish_list_update_date",new Date());
                    updateWishList(response);
                    deferred.resolve(response);
                })
                .error(function (response) {
                    deferred.reject(response);
                });
    }else{
        deferred.resolve(getWishList());
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a setInterval call like this,

```
var timer, delay = 604800000; //7 days counted in milliseconds.

timer = setInterval(function(){
    WishListService.getWishListTags(function(response) {
                var WISHLIST_TAGS_STORAGE_KEY = 'wishlist_tags';
                localStorageService.set(WISHLIST_TAGS_STORAGE_KEY, response.data);
            });
}, delay);
```

if you need it to stop at some point call

```
clearInterval(timer);
```